# SCons fails to find generated file

Tags: build, dependencies, scons

I am tring to generate some source file, and use the generated file to compile..

```
gen = env.Command("/tmp/dummy", "demo.json","demo.py $SOURCE > $TARGET")
env.AlwaysBuild(gen)

bin=env.Program(target='demo', source=[Glob("*.cc")])
env.Depends(bin, gen)
```

the gen will generate required demo.cc

> gen = env.Command("/tmp/dummy", "demo.json","demo.py $SOURCE > $TARGET")

But get error when compiling demo as follows:

> failed: Source `demo.cc' not found, needed by target`demo.o'.

By ls demo.cc, I am sure that the required file demo.cc is indeed generated in the correct directory.

The cause should be something with dependency. Noted that I specify explicit dependency of the bin on demo.cc. Still failed.

Any ideas why ?

===== More details =====

Every clean build, i.e. scons -c && scons -j4, works. But afterword build fails even with the demo.cc file in place.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling *SCons* that the result (=target) of your `env.Command()` is "`/tmp/dummy`". Try to use

```
gen = env.Command("demo.cc", "demo.json","demo.py $SOURCE > $TARGET")
```

instead, such that *SCons* can pick up the dependency automatically. You don't need the explicit `Depends()`.

Comment: The issue is that demo.cc is not the output of demo.py. demo.py will generate internally many files, demo.cc is one of them..

Comment: And how do you expect SCons to know this? What you actually need is an Emitter then, which returns all the target files created by your command. Have a look at our [ToolsForFools guide](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools) where you can find an example for this.

Comment: will check later. What is the problem of my current method? I used always and depends to explicitly specify the dependency, still not working?

Comment: Is the list of files generated deterministic? for a.json, you get 10 files named something predictable? Or does it depend on the contents of the json file?

Comment: @bdbaddogyep, for each demo.json, 2 and only 2 files named demo.cc and demo.h will be generated.